# Flex applications on Windows Phone 7

Tags: apache-flex, windows-phone-7, mobile

I'm evaluating Flex 4.5 for use as a mobile development platform. The demo version of the IDE supports android and promises to support iPhone development in future. There's no mention of Windows Phone 7. Usually, this is the sort of thing that google excels at but in this case, I've come up empty handed. I've found many contradictory reports of Adobe supporting WP7, then not supporting it, then supporting it but not in the initial release.

Has anyone come across any official announcements from Adobe on this? I understand that companies change their priorities and business relationships change so I'm not looking for a crystal ball, I'd just like to see the latest communication from Adobe on this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex 4.5 can currently be used on Android and iPhone, however WinPhone7 is kind of out of the loop for now.  There has been some demos of it shown, but who knows when Microsoft/Adobe will work together to get Flash out on Internet Explorer mobile or get to having Air on WinPhone7.

I know personally that Adobe is aiming for it, but not sure how much of a priority it is since WinPhone7 is still an underdog in this arena.  My feeling is that it will come, but not just yet.

Answer (score 0):

Flex/Flash hass not been mentioned on any public timelines for Windows Phone 7.
I think it's safe to assume that you won't see it any time soon.